# How can I seperate each instance of a specific column value from a dataframe on a bar grpah?

Tags: python, dataframe, bar-chart, plotly-dash, plotly-express

I have a data frame which I have
4 columns
“Location, Sample_Date, SRB, APB”
I’ve made the “Location” the index.
And within this DF there could be multiple instances of a “Location”.

I’ve started creating my first Dash app and I have a dropdown and a graph.

I would like the dropdown to show only uniques values of “Location”.

Once chosen, I want it to show Each instances of that Location SRB and APB

X - Axis: each “Sample_ Dates”

Y- Axis: each value of “SRB” and “APB” for the corresponding “Sample_Dates”

Showing multiple sets of Bar graphs for each instance.

```
from gc import callbacks
from itertools import groupby
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input,Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## data sources to be used for this project

bacteria = pd.read_excel("data/Bacteria_Firebird_ALL_2_6_2022.xlsx")

## cleaning DataFrame
bacteria = bacteria[['Location','SRB','APB','Sample Date', 'Cellular (pg per mL)']].copy()
bacteria.set_index('Location')
bacteria.sort_values(by="Sample Date")

# Initiation of Dash App
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor':colors['background']},
    children=[
        html.H1(
            children="Well Site Inspection",
            style={
                'textAlign':'center',
                'color':colors['text']
                ,'padding':5
                }
            ),
        html.H4(
            children="Analyzed report for a well pull, including historic data colleted for the well.",
            style={
                'textAlign':'center',
                'color':'#000000'
            }
            ),
        dcc.Markdown(successful_Bacteria_Program,style={'color':colors["text"],'textAlign':'center'}),

        dcc.Dropdown(
            bacteria['Location'].unique(),
           id="dropdown",
           clearable=True,
           placeholder= "Please select a location.."
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
           id="Bacteria",
        ),
         dcc.Markdown(srb_apb_MD , style={'color':colors["text"],'padding':20}),
])

@app.callback(
    Output("Bacteria", "figure"),
    Input("dropdown", "value")

)

def updateDashboard(my_dropdown):

    df_bacteria = bacteria[bacteria['Location'] == my_dropdown]
    print(df_bacteria)

    bar_chart = px.bar(
        data_frame=df_bacteria,
        x = df_bacteria["Location"],
        y = ["SRB","APB"],
        title="Bacteria Sampling",
        barmode='group'
      
        )

    return bar_chart
```

Comment: Do you have sample data that you can provide? I believe that the percentage of responses we receive will be higher if there is.

Comment: a sample of the excel? @r-beginners